# How to place a texture in a specific location?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

In my code, I'm mixing two textures. I want to position a texture at any place on the plane but when I add an offset to the texture UV XY coordinate the image just gets stretched.

```
offsetText1 = vec2(0.1,0.1);       
vec4 displacement  = texture2D(utexture1,vUv+offsetText1);
```

How do I move the texture to any position without stretching it?

**VERTEX SHADER:**

```
  
  varying vec2 vUv;
  uniform sampler2D utexture1;
  uniform sampler2D utexture2;
  varying vec2 offsetText1;

  void main() {
      offsetText1 = vec2(0.1,0.1);
      vUv = uv;
      vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      vec4 displacement  = texture2D(utexture1,vUv+offsetText1);
      vec4 displacement2 = texture2D(utexture2,vUv);
      modelPosition.z   += displacement.r*1.0;
      modelPosition.z   += displacement2.r*40.0;
      gl_Position       = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelPosition;
  }
```

**FRAGMENT SHADER:**

```
  #ifdef GL_ES
  precision highp float;
  #endif
  uniform sampler2D utexture1;
  uniform sampler2D utexture2;
  varying vec2 vUv;
  varying vec2 offsetText1;

  void main() {
      vec3 c;
      vec4 Ca = texture2D(utexture1,vUv+offsetText1 );
      vec4 Cb = texture2D(utexture2,vUv);
      c       = Ca.rgb * Ca.a + Cb.rgb * Cb.a * (2.0 - Ca.a);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);
  }
```

image with `offsetText1 = vec2(0.0,0.0);`
[no stretching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GupWS.png)

image with `offsetText1 = vec2(0.1,0.1);` image is being stretched from the top right corner.
[stretching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSpLH.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's the behavior of textures. They extend in the range from `[0, 1]`, so when you go beyond 1 or below 0, they'll "wrap". You need to tell it what to do when wrapping. Do you want it to repeat, stretch, or mirror?

You could establish this with the [`texture.wrapS` and `.wrapT` properties](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.wrapS), which accepts one of 3 values:

```
THREE.RepeatWrapping
THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping
```

If you want to just show white where the texture extends out of bounds, then you'd have to do that programmatically in your shader code. Here's some pseudocode:

```
if (uv < 0 || > 1)
   color = white
```